# Phoenix equivalent of Rails' params[:controller]

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to find the Phoenix Equivalent of rails' `params[:controller]`, so that I can serve stylesheets and javascript files based on the controller rendering the view.

In Rails, you could simply do this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', params[:controller] %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', params[:controller] %>
```

*Source: [Rails Asset Pipeline - Controller Specific Assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets)*

---

I'm trying to do the same thing in Phoenix. I'm separating my Sass files according to their controllers. Maybe something like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/app.css") %>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= static_path(@conn, "/css/#{@controller}.css") %>">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your class from `Phoenix.Controller.controller_module/1` https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/3fc98f8b18095b6d155f5afd824f7c5e24447187/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L112-L116